# Explain behaviour of compound shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Can someone explain this behaviour?

I was expecting to get the same visual result from both, `Minus front` and `Compound shape`. Instead, it seems that compound shape will:

- Unite the two fills of the object in the white fill. The fills are not really united, but it feels like it.
- Leave the grey fill but removing the transform
- Finally, perform the compound shape operation

How could I get the same result as Minus front but keeping the non-destructive ability of compound shapes?

[image: Minus front vs compound shape]

---

Just to clarify (the Appearance belongs to the shape after compound, and the transform of the second fill is gone):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you actually *want* a compound shape here. Compound shapes are only useful when one shape *completely encompasses* another shape. That doesn't appear to be the case in your sample images.

You **can** use `Minus Front` **non-destructively** though.

Simply hold down the **<kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key** when you click the `Minus Front` button on the **Pathfinder Panel**. That will perform the operation in a **non-destructive** manner, allowing for further editing.

[image]

The shadow needs to be treated as a separate object and not part of the combined shape. Pathfinder or compound shapes won't alter all 3 objects correctly.

You **can** use Minus Front, and **then** add an **extra fill via the Appearance Panel** and move it via `Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform` to create the shadow.

[image]

Comment: This is actually how I did it, with the `Alt` key, which creates a compound shape. The strange thing is that with the shadow as a fill it will ruin the result - whereas the `minus front` works just fine. I thought `minus front` would just `compound shape` + `expand`. Keeping shadows as different objects is not an option, firstly because there can be many objects and I cannot be manually keeping track of shadows positions. Secondly because, as you see in your image, the compound shape did not affect both the shadow and the front as the `minus front` did.

Comment: @user1156544 Honestly.. I'd simply use minus front, then add an **extra fill** via the **Appearance Panel** to add the shadow shape. you don't *really* need that third shape.

Comment: But there is no extra shape... they are all fills. one white, one grey, in the same object. The compound shape (Alt+Minus front) just did a strange thing on the second fill, and removed the transform so the grey is hidden behind the white in my image

Comment: @user1156544 simply based on your sample images, the shadow *appears* to be a third shape. In any event, check updated answer.

Comment: How you did it is exactly how I did it from the beginning. The issue is that if I apply the `Compound shape` after the shadow has been created (an extra `Fill` with `Transform`) then I get a strange outcome. If I apply the compound first, then it is fine, but I prefer not to un-do all shadows to apply first the compounds.

Comment: Sorry. I don't really know what to tell you. In order to performs the Pathfinder operation, Pathfinder expands effects when possible.